# Wordpress Site Hacked generating a huge error_log file

Tags: php, wordpress, error-log

I noticed that my one of my websites got hacked today and am in the process of cleaning it all up. I backed up the theme, database, and deleted all the files off the server but now I am having a major problem.

Since those files are no longer available the websites trying to pull a file off of my website are generating an error to my log file over and over and over causing it to fill my disk space quota up in a matter of minutes. Where do I start with fixing this type of problem? I tried blocking the offending ip address in the htacces file but it doesn't seem to be working the way I intended.

```
[Mon Oct 13 13:24:13 2014] [error] [client 178.151.4.236] File does not exist: /home/youngsco/public_html/index.php, referer: http://www.cardozo.us/
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, the error_log being generated is being placed in wp-content directory and is the only file in that directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are certain files that you need and index.php is the main one. If the website was being hacked, why do you need to remove files and folders?

You should clean up the database. Your source code should be fine. You should also disable your logging temporarily. You shouldn't use .htaccess to limit the IP but do this on a server level to block the hackers IP or setup something better and smarter on the server end. You should use something like a linux firewall if you're running linux like IPTABLES.

---

@Air Biscuit: I see. you had that type of attack. If the attack left random files and folders In that case I would wipe everything clean just to make sure everything is out. If you're running windows to server the files I would run some type of anti virus or Norton on it just to be sure and safe.

If you're on Linux/UNIX I would rm -f on the directory, get rid of the database all together.

To avoid anther attack in most cases it will happen again you should investigate into the IP and block the range; thats what they do in most times.

@Air Biscuit: If you're on a host that's on a shared host at hostgator, I would email them 
and let them know of what happened so they would secure it on their end also on incoming level. It would help them and you out.

Comment: The reason why was whatever got into the server left files and folders all through it with random names. I figured it would be easier to delete wordpress and start entirely fresh. It's a hosted site at hostgator.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to block via IP addresses because the chances of the IP address of the attacker—who is most likely using a botnet—will be constantly changing.

Unsure about disk quota or your hosting specifics, but errors being generated in a log caused by bad URLs is quite common. The idea that someone simply doing that would be causing you issues is a bit scary. It means that now pretty much anyone can continually slam your site with bogus URLs and your disk usage will go through the roof.

I would contact your ISP directly and see of they have another way of storing logs that does not interfere with your disk quota. It seems odd to me that an ISP in 2014 would be doing that. If anything—in my experience—system logs like that are made readable for users like you, but ultimately deeper in the system. Thus would not affect your quota.

Comment: One of my client in the past had the same issue; I used the ip to block a rannge of ips and the hack never repeated. I'm not sure because of the block range that this never happened again or if they gave up. One thing I don't agree with logs is that you don't need to log every single thing; I guess you can limit your logs in your apache config to keep it minimal and smaller.